# System.out.println( '3' + 0 );

Tags: java, char, int, system.out

So if you run the statement above `System.out.println( '3' +  0  );`

you get 51 as the output.

If you run another similar statement,

```
System.out.println(  3  + '0' );
```

you get the same result, which is 51.

However, if you run the third statement,

```
System.out.println( '3' + '0' )
```

then you get 99 as the result.

Can anyone explain what exactly is going on behind these three results?

Answer (score 1):

When you put numbers like 0 inside ' ' you are returning the ASCII/unicode value of 0 which in this case is 48 which is why when you add 3 to '0' you get 51.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this:

```
char c = '0';
int ascii = (int) c; // ASCII of '0' is 48
System.out.println( 3 + ascii);
```

Answer (score 1):

the ascii code of '3' is 51. when you add an integer 0 to it the result is 51 and it is printed. similarly the ascii code of '0' is 48 and you are adding 3 to it... but when you add '3' and '0' both in ascii format its adding 48 and 51 and hence the output is 99. this happens because of implicit type conversion in java.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `System.out.println( '3' +  0  );` or `System.out.println(  3  + '0' );`
here is a type switch, char 0 menas int 48, so `'3' + 0` means `51 + 0 = 51` so does `3 + '0'`.

So `'3' + '0'` means `51 + 48 = 99`.